# mysqldump of recent records

Tags: mysql

Does mysqldump (or some other command) have an option to dump ONLY recently updated rows? I haven't been able to find anything in the docs about this. thx.

Comment: What is the definition of *recent* in your case?

Comment: How are you defining recent?  Do you have a column in your schema that is the update time?

Comment: I have a timestamp column in each of my tables. "Recent" meaning whatever I tell it to be....ie "select * from table WHERE timestamp > ? "

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can give mysqldump a where clause using the --where option. So if you have a column called "modified" in your table and you want all rows modified in the past 2 hours you could do something like this:

```
mysqldump my_schema my_table --where="modified > now() - interval 2 hour"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the "into outfile" syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM table INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/result.txt'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
WHERE timestamp > ?
```

You can then import this later if necessary by using:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/result.txt' INTO table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Documentation on MySQL's site:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html

Answer (score 0):

From mysqldump manpage:

> --where=´where_condition´, -w ´where_condition´
>
> Dump only rows selected by the given WHERE condition. Quotes around the condition are mandatory if it contains spaces or
> other characters that are special to your
> command interpreter.
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
> --where="user=´jimf´"
> -w"userid>1"
> -w"userid<1"
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Define a view for the query you want.  Then use mysqldump on the view.